# Why does preg_replace_callback never fire in this function?

Tags: plugin-development

In the function below, the save_content function runs, but the doReplace does not (echo

"This is the doReplace" never shows. Any ideas why?

```
add_action('content_save_pre', 'save_content');

 function save_content($content){
  global $post;
  $mykeyword = rseo_getKeyword($post);
  $mykeyword = preg_quote($mykeyword, '/');
  $content = preg_replace_callback("/\b($mykeyword)\b/i","doReplace", $content);
 return $content;
 }

 function doReplace($matches)
 {
  echo "This is the doReplace";
  die;
  }
```

Comment: You do `global $post`, but at the time `content_save_pre` runs, no `$post` object exists (since you are right before saving it). Could this be your problem?

Comment: @Jan: that certainly sounds logical, but I'm able to echo $post->ID inside of save_content(). How can this be possible?

Comment: It appears a draft post is saved in the database, which is later overwritten by the actual post data? So I think you are getting the data of this draft post. Can you debug what `rseo_getKeyword()` returns there? Have you tried `preg_replace_callback()` with a fixed keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to return the data, not echo it..

```
function doReplace($matches) {
    return "This is the doReplace";
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Indeed, in a normal regex callback you want to return the replacement string. But Scott is probably debugging, and then this code should echo the output to the screen and die, no?

Comment: Jan is correct. I'm just debugging the code.

Comment: But, still... nothing gets echoed to the screen during the save_content, does it? I was under the impression it was done as an AJAX request, so trying to echo something would have no visual effect. I would think you'd be better off returning a value into your post that you could check for later.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the preg_quote() call be used in an array map call? If you're feeding it something like "foo|bar" it'll get escaped as "foo\|bar", which won't match anything... Better use something like this:

```
// uncomment in case you're returning a string:
// $kw = explode('|', $kw);
// create a new function if php 5.3 is not an option
$regex = array_map(function($in) {
  return preg_quote($in, '/');
}, $kw);
$regex = implode('|', $regex);
```